# QNetworkAccessManager: Posting files via HTTP

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I just need to use QNetworkAccessManager to upload multiple files on an apache server with PHP.

I'm asking here because I'm new to Python ad QT (PySide) and I would like to know if someone have a tutorial or example of code (in python) demonstrating this.

*Note: If this kind of content is not available I will try to do it myself and share a tutorial after.*

Comment: Starting with Qt 4.8 (and pyside 1.0.8), you can use [QHttpMultiPart](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.8/qhttpmultipart.html).

Comment: I'm working with QT 4.7 but thanks for the link :)!

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it's the best way but it's working fine.

```
    class Upload():
        def __init__(self):
            self.url     = QUrl("http://www.website.com/up.php")
            self.manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()

        def sendRequest(self, replayfile):
            self.request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(self.url)              

            self.request.setRawHeader("Host", str(self.url.host()));
            self.request.setRawHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x");

            fp = QFile(replayfile)
            fp.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
            bytes = QByteArray()

            bytes.append("--AaB03x\r\n")
            bytes.append("Content-Disposition: ")
            bytes.append("form-data; name=\"replay\"; filename=\"" + QByteArray(str(QFileInfo(replayfile).fileName())) + "\"\r\n")
            bytes.append("Content-Type: %s\r\n"%mimetypes.guess_type(str(replayfile))[0])
            bytes.append("\r\n")
            bytes.append(fp.readAll())

            fp.close()       

            bytes.append("\r\n")
            bytes.append("--AaB03x--")

            contentLength = bytes.length()
            self.request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", "%s" % contentLength)       

            self.manager.post(self.request, bytes)
```

In PHP:

```
    Array
    (
        [replay] => Array
            (
                [name] => test.SC2Replay
                [type] => None
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpK6tChh
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 9882
            )

    )
```